# How to implement server and client in android with json

Tags: android, json, server

I have a question about a local server and parsing JSON. I have to make a application for school and you have to parse JSON with a local server with IP and port.

This is the server class:

```
/**
* Created by Charlie on 26-3-2015.
*/
public class Server extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

private String message;
private String ip;
public static int port = 4444;
private String serverResponse = null;

public Server(String ip, int port, String message ) {
    super();
    //IP, Port en bericht om naar server te sturen
    this.message = message;
    this.ip = ip;
    this.port = port;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        Socket serverSocket = new Socket();
        serverSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(this.ip, this.port), 4444);

        this.sendMessage(message, serverSocket);

        InputStream input;

        try {
            input = serverSocket.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader responseStreamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
            String line = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = responseStreamReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }
            responseStreamReader.close();

            this.serverResponse = stringBuilder.toString();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        System.out.println("Response: " + serverResponse);

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        Log.d("debug", "can't find host");
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        Log.d("debug", "time-out");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return serverResponse;
}

private void sendMessage(String message, Socket serverSocket) {
    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = null;

    try {
        outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(serverSocket.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (outputStreamWriter != null) {
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(bufferedWriter, true);

        writer.println(message);
    }
}
 }
```

And this is a class which calls the data:

```
public class HoofdschermFragment extends android.app.Fragment {

public static String serverIp;
public static int serverPort = 4444;
public static ArrayList<String> slotenLijst;
public static ArrayList<JSONObject> beknopteInformatieSlotlijst;
public static String informatieslotbeknopt = null;
private static View rootview;
private Spinner sloten_spinner;
public static String SlotNaam;
public static Boolean initieleVerbinding = true;
public static int GeselecteerdSlot;
public static int GeselecteerdePositie;

public static android.app.Fragment fragmentslotinformatie = new InformatieSlotFragment();

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hoofdscherm, container, false);

    //als eerste keer verbinding is, haal alles op uit server, zo niet, laatst opgehaalde data weer invullen
    if(initieleVerbinding == true) {
        dataOphalen();
        dataInvullen();
    } else {
        dataInvullen();
        sloten_spinner.setSelection(GeselecteerdSlot);
    }
    return rootview;
}

public void dataOphalen() {

    //ophalen van de services
    slotenLijst = new ArrayList<String>();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("slotenlijst", "");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String response = null;
    try {
        try {
            // Dit IP adres moet IP adres van server zijn.
            response = new Server(serverIp,
                    serverPort, jsonObject.toString()).execute().get();

        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (response == null) {

        Toast.makeText(rootview.getContext(), "Kan helaas geen verbinding maken met de server.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        // Haal de null naam weg van de JSONArray (Voorkomt error)
        String jsonFix = response.replace("null", "");

        JSONArray JArray = null;
        try {
            JArray = new JSONArray(jsonFix);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JSONObject jObject = null;
        String value = null;
        slotenLijst = new ArrayList<String>();

        //zet alle services in een JArray
        for (int i = 0; i < JArray.length(); i++) {
            try {
                jObject = JArray.getJSONObject(i);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                value = jObject.getString("Slot");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            slotenLijst.add(value);

        }
        // korte informatie over elke dienst ophalen, in een ArrayList zetten als JSONObjecten
        beknopteInformatieSlotlijst = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
        JSONObject beknoptjObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < slotenLijst.size(); i++) {
                beknoptjObject.put("Informatiebeknopt", slotenLijst.get(i));
                try {
                    try {
                        informatieslotbeknopt = new Server(serverIp,
                                serverPort, beknoptjObject.toString()).execute().get();
                        //exceptions afvangen
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                String infoFix = informatieslotbeknopt.replace("null", "");
                JSONObject fixedjObject = new JSONObject(infoFix);
                beknopteInformatieSlotlijst.add(fixedjObject);

                Log.i("Informatiebeknopt", infoFix);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //aangeven dat app al eens eerder gedraait heeft
        initieleVerbinding = false;

    }


    // Locate the spinner in activity_main.xml
    sloten_spinner = (Spinner) rootview.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    // Spinner adapter

    sloten_spinner
            .setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(rootview.getContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                    slotenLijst));

    // Spinner on item click listener
    sloten_spinner
            .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                           View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                    // Locate the textviews in activity_main.xml
                    TextView beknopteinfoslot = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.textviewbeknoptinfoslot);

                    try {
                        // Set the text followed by the position
                        beknopteinfoslot.setText(beknopteInformatieSlotlijst.get(position).getString("Informatiebeknopt"));
                        SlotNaam = slotenLijst.get(position);

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                }
            });

}

//opgehaalde data in de spinner zetten en beknopte tekst over diensten weergeven
private void dataInvullen() {
    // Locate the spinner in activity_main.xml
    sloten_spinner = (Spinner) rootview.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    // Spinner adapter
    sloten_spinner
            .setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(rootview.getContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                    slotenLijst));

    // Spinner on item click listener
    sloten_spinner
            .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                           View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    // Locate the textviews in activity_main.xml
                    TextView beknopteinfo = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.textviewbeknoptinfoslot);

                    try {
                        // Set the text followed by the position
                        beknopteinfo.setText(beknopteInformatieSlotlijst.get(position).getString("informatieslotbeknopt"));
                        SlotNaam = slotenLijst.get(position);
                        getActivity().setTitle(SlotNaam);
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });

    //naar servicepagina navigeren en dus informatie ophalen over de geselecteerdePositie
    Button infoslotbutton = (Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.infoslotbutton);
    infoslotbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            GeselecteerdePositie = sloten_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, fragmentslotinformatie)
                    .commit();
        }
    });

}
  }
```

I have also an Activity where the user can fill in the IP, so that the app can make a connection with the server with the given IP.
I know how I can figure out my own local IP adres. My teacher also gave a ClientCommunicator Class, SlotData Class and an other class. What I don't understand is, how can I implement these classes to make my application parse the JSON Data?

ClientCommunicator Class:

```
  static ArrayList<String> getCategories() 
{
    categorielijst = new ArrayList<String>();

    //aanmaken van een nieuwe jsonobject
    JSONObject categorieJObject = new JSONObject();
    try 
    {
        //verzenden van het jsonobject wat de server verwacht
        categorieJObject.put("categorielijst", "" );
    } 
    catch (JSONException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String response = null;
    try 
    {
        try 
        {
            //servercommunicator om verbinding te maken met de server
            response = new ServerCommunicator( activity, url, 4444,    categorieJObject.toString()).execute().get();
        } 
        catch (ExecutionException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e1) 
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
        //om errors te voorkomen
        String jsonFix = response.replace("null", "");

        JSONArray categorieJArray = null;
        try 
        {
            categorieJArray = new JSONArray(jsonFix);
        } 
        catch (JSONException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JSONObject jObject = null;
        String value = null;
        categorielijst = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0 ; i < categorieJArray.length(); i++) 
        {
            try 
            {
                jObject = (JSONObject) categorieJArray.getJSONObject(i);
            } 
            catch (JSONException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try 
            {
                value = jObject.getString("naam");
            } 
            catch (JSONException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            categorielijst.add(value);
        }
        //geef de lijst met categorie�n terug zodat deze in de spinner geplaatst kan worden
        return categorielijst;
    }
```

SlotData class:

```
  package hsl.imtpmd.eindopdrachtserver;

  import java.util.HashMap;

 public class SlotData
{
//singleton
private static SlotData _instance;
public static SlotData getInstance()
{
    if( _instance == null )
        _instance = new SlotData();

    return _instance;
}



private String[] sloten = { "Sleutel slotsystemen", "RFID slotsystemen", "Biometrische slotsystemen"};
private HashMap<String, String> slotInfo;
private HashMap<String, String> slotInfoBeknopt;

private SlotData()
{   
    slotInfo = new HashMap<String,String>();
    slotInfoBeknopt = new HashMap<String,String>();

    slotInfo.put( "Sleutel slotsystemen", "De meest eenvoudige vorm van beveiliging zijn sloten die per sleutel geopend kunnen worden. Dit is een relatief goedkoop systeem maar brengt enige veiligheidsproblemen met zich mee. Voor beveiliging van ruimtes die weinig waardevolle zaken bevatten is dit systeem een uitstekende uitkomst." );
    slotInfo.put( "RFID slotsystemen", "RFID authenticatie is met de huidige techniek snel en gemakkelijk te implementeren om elke ruimte af te sluiten. Dankzij de digitalisering kunnen gebruikers getraceerd worden en bestaat de mogelijkheid een geschiedenis van ruimtegebruik aan te leggen. Dit resulteert in verhoogde beveiliging." );
    slotInfo.put( "Biometrische slotsystemen", "Biometrische authenticatie en authorizatie is de meest geavanceerde vorm van beveiliging. Dit systeem werkt nagenoeg feilloos en garandeerd een zeer hoge veiligheid van uw waardevolle bezittingen. Biometrische authorizatie kan op verschillende niveaus worden toegepast, van vingerafdruk tot irisscan." );

    slotInfoBeknopt.put( "Sleutel slotsystemen", "Eenvoudig, snel en goedkoop uw bezit achter slot en grendel!" );
    slotInfoBeknopt.put( "RFID slotsystemen", "Digitale beveiliging voor 100% zekerheid!" );
    slotInfoBeknopt.put( "Biometrische slotsystemen", "Authenticatie en authorizatie op persoonlijk niveau!" );
}

public String[] getSloten()
{
    return sloten;
}

public String getInformatie( String slot )
{
    return slotInfo.get( slot );
}

public String getInformatieBeknopt( String slot )
{
    return slotInfoBeknopt.get( slot );
}
 }
```

And the other class:

```
 package hsl.imtpmd.eindopdrachtserver;

 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
 import javax.swing.JTextArea;

 public class DeSleutelaar extends JFrame
{
private Server server;

public DeSleutelaar()
{
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    this.setSize( 400, 400 );
    this.setLocationRelativeTo( null );

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord( true );
    textArea.setEditable( false );
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( textArea );
    this.add( scrollPane );

    this.setVisible( true );

    server = new Server( textArea );
}


@Override
public void finalize()
{
    server.requestStop();
}


public static void main( String[] args )
{
    new DeSleutelaar();
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you are using Sockets (TCP), even though the server is probably using HTTP (HTTPUrlConnection). I'm not sure what your Server class does.

Comment: `Socket serverSocket = new Socket();` O how awfull. Don't name your Socket instance a ServerSocket. ServerSockte is the server socket. Not a client socket.

Comment: So you suppose us to analyse all that code? You did not even tell where you get a json text. You should do the analysing and tell exactly what you have where in your code. You ask way to much. Do you understand all these classes?

Comment: @greenapps That is the code my teachter gave me. I understand all these classes and I made my app already, the only thing I have to understand how to make these server and client classes work so that the JSON Data can be showed in my app.

Comment: If you understood all those classes you would also know where you had to apply them. So where is the problem? You posted code for a server and a client and several classes but did not tell if they were for the server or the client. There is already json in the code but you did not tell how it flows or it should flow; from server to client or from client to server or both. `How to implement server and client in android`. No it seems that the server is for your PC. `This is the server class: `. No. That is code for a client.

Comment: `public class Server extends AsyncTask`. Terrible. For code that should be readable please change to`public class ClientTask extends AsyncTask` . `ClientCommunicator Class: `. That is not a class. It's only a function. Please state where you need help. For your server or your client or both.

Comment: @greenapps I need help with the part that I don't know how I can request JSON data from my local  (PC or emulator) server and parse that into my application. I know the code my teacher gave me is terrible.

Comment: `I know the code my teacher gave me is terrible`. I did not say that. Those are your words.  `* Created by Charlie on 26-3-2015.`. My remarks were there.

Comment: `from my local (PC or emulator) `. I do not believe that your server would run or on your pc or on your emulator. Please elaborate.

Comment: @greenapps I would like to know how I can make my app a client-server app, which implements both clientside en serverside for requesting en parsing JSON

Comment: You are asking way to much. That you want to make a client-server app is ok. But the client and server will exchange text messages. That those text messages will contain json text is irrelevant first. So you could start with constructing such an app. If it runs and you can exchange messages then you can make json text messages out of it.